# How to show $M\subseteq J\left( R\right)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. Set $M=\{ x\in R|\forall y\in R\Rightarrow 1-xy\;\; \text{unitary in}\; R\}$ and $J\left( R\right) =\cap \{ I|I\unlhd R, I \text{is a maximal ideal}\}$.

> How to show that $M\subseteq J\left( R\right)$?

Comment: You may want to fix your question.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you mean $M=\{x∈R|∀y∈R⇒1−xy \text{ unitary in R}\}$ and $J(R)=\bigcap _{I\subseteq R \text{ and $I$ is a maximal ideal}}I$ and these are just typos.
Let $I$ and $x$ be as above and assume $x\notin I$. Then the ideal $J$ generated by $I$ and $x$ is already $R$.
Hence there are $r\in R$ and $i\in I$, such that $1=rx+i$. Thus, $1-rx=i$ is invertible. But $i\in I$. Hence $I$ contains a unit and we obtain the contradiction $I=R$.

Comment: You can remove references to $s$.